# Facebook read action showing in activity log but not showing on timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I am using built-in read action for my news reader app. But this action not appearing in user's timeline , instead its listing in activity log.
My action is approved by facebook and using publish_action permission . Plz help.

Comment: Open Graph activities initially show up only under the Recent Activities section. Once the app has generated considerable traffic, it will start to show up on timelines. The goal for a developer should be to focus on improving the quality of the app, and make it more engaging thereby attracting more users.

Comment: @DeepakLakshmanan is that a recent change? My actions have been appearing in the timeline all along but since last week they only show up under "recent activities"

Answer (score 0):

you have to add fb:explicitly_shared=true in your code and also add the same permission in your action setting page[there is a tick box you have to select]
refer this documentation
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.0#actionlinks
the same can be found under the publishing action section